# Taking a generator out of a context manager

Tags: python, generator, contextmanager

I just saw the following code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from future_builtins import map # generator

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    linegen = map(str.strip, f)

# file handle should be closed here

for line in linegen:
    # using the generator now
    print(line)
```

What happens in this case? Is the context manager smart enough to know that `linegen` still has a reference to the file handle, such that it's not closed when the context is left? Or is this potentially unsafe?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: It's not *potentially* unsafe, it *is* unsafe; you can see the exception raised by trying to read from a closed file.

Comment: this simply looks wrong

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem being asked about is readily observed by running the code.

Comment: The entire point of the `with` block is to guarantee that the file is closed when you leave that scope. It would be non-sensical to keep it open.

Comment: In Python 2, `map()` will return a list, not a generator, so the file not being open any longer wouldn't be a problem. Did they mention which version of Python was being used wherever you saw the code? From the comments it looks like version 3, so yes it would cause an error. Try it and find out.

Comment: The problem is that this could break Python 2 code being ported to python 3. It works fine in Python 2 because `map` does not return a generator

Comment: The `from future` line implies this is Python 2

Comment: Given this conflict, there's something important to be learned by others. I don't think this question should be closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those breaking changes in Python 3.

Your question title (Taking a *generator* ...) implies you are reading it as Python 3 code.

But the statement

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

implies it was written for Python 2

In Python 2, `map` returns an actual list - and thus this code is both perfectly safe and extrmely sensible (i.e open a file, read all lines,s tripping them as you go, then close the file)

```
In [2]: with open('README.md','r') as f:
   ...:     lines = map(str.strip, f)
   ...:     
In [3]: lines
Out[3]: 
['ASM',
 '============',
 '',
```

In Python 3, the same code throws an exception

```
In [1]: with open('README.md','r') as f:
    lines = map(str.strip, f)
   ...:     
In [2]: lines
Out[2]: <map at 0x7f4d393c3ac8>
In [3]: list(lines)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2666a44c63b5> in <module>()
----> 1 list(lines)

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

If you want a version-safe implementation of this you need to either convert the generator to a list

```
lines = list(map(str.strip, f))
```

or just use a list comprehension

```
lines = [l.strip() for l in f]
```

Comment: `from future_builtins import map` makes `map` a generator also in Python 2. I was interested in the priorities of open reference vs. leaving context. It seems context wins, since everyone is consistently getting the exception. By all means, feel free to close the question.